# Terminal doesn't show output after `npm start`

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, gatsby, zsh, npm-start

After running `npm start`, my terminal doesn't show all the output, see the following screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sTjiE.png)

I have tried to copy and paste the empty part to a text editor, and there are indeed text there:

```
for instantaneous feedback in your development server. Recommended for versions of React >= 17.0.

There are 3 other flags available that you might be interested in:
- FAST_DEV · Enable all experiments aimed at improving develop server start time
- DEV_SSR · (Umbrella Issue) · Server Side Render (SSR) pages on full reloads during develop. Helps 
you detect SSR bugs and fix them without needing to do full builds.
- PRESERVE_WEBPACK_CACHE · (Umbrella Issue) · Don't delete webpack's cache when changing 
gatsby-node.js & gatsby-config.js files.
- PRESERVE_FILE_DOWNLOAD_CACHE · (Umbrella Issue) · Don't delete the downloaded files cache when 
changing gatsby-node.js & gatsby-config.js files.
- ...
```

If I run `npm start` to build a second project, my terminal has no problem showing all the output. So I guess it is not a problem with my terminal, but rather some packages in the first project. I know the first project uses Gastby while the second one doesn't, so it might be the reason.

I'm new to this field and have no clue what could go wrong. I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and using zsh if that helps. Does anyone have an idea what could possible go wrong? Or what are some key words I should search to find a solution? Thanks!

Comment: If you switch to a terminal with white background, can you see the text?

Comment: I tried to switch the theme color, even to other terminals (Guake) and the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

I have also experienced the issue on an Ubuntu machine. It only happens using background terminals, with IDE/VSCode terminals work perfectly fine so my suggestion is to use the built-in terminal rather than ZSH.

You can try changing the Node version of your project to check if the "issue" persists.